# Kernel not executed, after being loaded

Tags: assembly, kernel, nasm, qemu, bootloader

#### Issue

Kernel seems to be loaded, by the bootloader, but no further execution. It seems like there is a problem either with the way I run the image with `qemu` or with the way the kernel is loaded.

#### Source code

*makefile*

```
bold=`tput bold`

black=`tput setaf 0`
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
yellow=`tput setaf 3`
blue=`tput setaf 4`
magenta=`tput setaf 5`
cyan=`tput setaf 6`
white=`tput setaf 7`

reset=`tput sgr0`


default: build run

build:
    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiling Bootloader"
    @nasm -f bin src/bootloader.asm -o bin/boot.bin

    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiling Kernel"
    @nasm -f bin src/kernel.asm -o bin/kernel.bin

    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiling the OS"
    @cat bin/boot.bin bin/kernel.bin > bin/os.bin

    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiled."

run:
    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Launching the VM:"
    @qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -drive format=raw,file=bin/os.bin -m 4G -cpu host -smp 2 -vga virtio -display sdl,gl=on

clean:
    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Cleaning..."
    @rm -rfv bin/*.bin
    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Cleaned"
```

**helper functions:**
*src/utils/print.asm*

```
print_string_buffer:
    ; The function prints a string from the buffer 
    ; stored in the SI register, it expects a 
    ; null symbol to be found in the buffer.  
    ; Parameters:
    ;   si - memory offset to the buffer 

    push si
    push ax

.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done

    ; display character
    mov ah, 0x0A
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov cx, 1
    int 0x10

    ; move cursor
    mov ah, 0x02
    inc dl
    int 0x10

    jmp .loop

.done:
    pop  ax
    pop  si
    ret
```

*src/disk.asm*

```
disk_load:
    ; The function reads DH number of sectors
    ; into ES:BX memory location from drive DL
    ; Parameters:
    ;   es:bx - buffer memory address 

    push dx             ; store dx on stack for error handling later 

    mov ah, 0x02        ; INT 13H 02H, BIOS read disk sectors into memory
    mov al, dh          ; number of sectors
    mov ch, 0x00        ; cylinder  
    mov dh, 0x00        ; head
    mov cl, 0x02        ; start reading sector (2 is the sector after the bootloader)
    int 0x13            ; BIOS interrupt for disk functions 

    jc disk_error       ; checks if CF (carry flag) set to 1

    pop dx              ; restore dx value from stack
    cmp dh, al          ; checks dh (number of read sectors) vs al (number of desired read sectors) 
    jne disk_error      ; if not the desired amount of sectors were read, then error 

    call disk_success
    ret                 ; return to caller

disk_error:
    mov si, DISK_ERROR_MESSAGE
    call print_string_buffer
    hlt

disk_success:
    mov si, DISK_SUCCESS_MESSAGE
    call print_string_buffer

    ; move cursor
    mov ah, 0x02
    inc dh
    mov dl, 0
    int 0x10

    ret

DISK_ERROR_MESSAGE: db "could not read from disk", 0
DISK_SUCCESS_MESSAGE: db "successfully loaded the disk", 0
```

**bootloader**
*src/bootloader.asm*

```
org 0x7C00

%define color_black   0
%define color_blue    1
%define color_green   2
%define color_cyan    3
%define color_red     4
%define color_magenta 5
%define color_orange  6
%define color_gray    7
%define color_yellow  14
%define color_white   15

;;;;;;;;
; INIT ;
;;;;;;;;

clear_screen:
    ; Int 0x10
    ; AH = 06h
    ; AL = number of lines by which to scroll up (00h = clear entire window)
    ; BH = attribute used to write blank lines at bottom of window
    ; CH, CL = row, column of window's upper left corner
    ; DH, DL = row, column of window's lower right corner

    mov ax, 0x0600                              ; AH = 6 = Scroll Window Up, AL = 0 = clear window
    mov bh, color_black << 4 | color_magenta    ; Attribute to clear screen with (White on Red)
    xor cx, cx                                  ; Clear window from 0, 0
    mov dx, 25 << 8 | 80                        ; Clear window to 24, 80
    int 0x10                                    ; Clear the screen

    mov ah, 0x02                                ; Set cursor
    mov bh, 0x00                                ; Page 0
    mov dx, 0x00                                ; Row = 0, col = 0
    int 0x10



set_custom_cursor:
    ; Int 0x10
    ; AH = 01h
    ; CH = start scan line of character matrix (0-1fH; 20H=no cursor)
    ; CL = end scan line of character matrix (0-1fH)

    mov ax, 0x0100                              ; AH = 1 = Set Cursor Shape & Size, AL = 0 = nothing
    mov ch, 0x1                                 ; Sets the width of the cursor, the higher the thicker
    mov cl, 0x10                                ; Sets the height of the cursor, the less the higher
    int 0x10

; bootloader start-up message
mov si, start_up_message 
call print_string_buffer


; set up DX for disk loading
mov dh, 0x1       ; number of sectors that will be loaded into memory
mov dl, 0x0       ; drive number to load (0 = boot disk)

; set up ES:BX memory address to load sectors into
mov bx, 0x1000  ; load sector to memory address 0x1000
mov es, bx      ; ES = 0x1000 
mov bx, 0x0       ; ES:BX = 0x1000:0 (segment:offset)

; set up segment registers for RAM
mov ax, 0x1000
mov ds, ax      ; data segment
mov es, ax      ; extra segment
mov fs, ax       
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax      ; stack segment


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; BOOTLOADER ENTRY POINT ; 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
call disk_load  ; loads kernel into memory
jmp 0x1000:0x0


;;;;;;;;;;;
; IMPORTS ;
;;;;;;;;;;;

%include "src/utils/print.asm"
%include "src/disk.asm"


;;;;;;;
; VAR ;
;;;;;;;

start_up_message: db "Bootloader bootstrap", 0


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; MAGIC NUMBERS ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

**kernel**
*src/kernel.asm*

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; ENTRY POINT ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

start:
    mov si, OS_VERSION 
    call print_string_buffer

    hlt


;;;;;;;;;;;
; IMPORTS ;
;;;;;;;;;;;

%include "src/utils/print.asm"


OS_VERSION: db "OS v1.0", 0

; sector padding
times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

---

After running `make`, the following project's structure is seen:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── boot.bin
│   ├── kernel.bin
│   └── os.bin
├── makefile
└── src
    ├── bootloader.asm
    ├── disk.asm
    ├── kernel.asm
    └── utils
        └── print.asm
```

I tried to make the jump from the bootloader to the kernel at a different location, by setting `ES:BX` registers to values, like `0x0:0x1000`. Also, I increased the memory of the virtual machine to 4GB of RAM. None of the following helped.

Any theories or ideas will be helpful. Thanks.

---

#### Update on new findings

Making a floopy image and running it in the VirtualBox seems to work just fine. Whereas the same floopy image still freezes after the execution of the bootloader, not reaching the kernel. Thus the source code should be right, and the issue is with the `qemu` arguments.

*changes of the makefile*:

```
...
build:
    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiling Bootloader"
    @nasm -f bin src/bootloader.asm -o bin/boot.bin

    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiling Kernel"
    @nasm -f bin src/kernel.asm -o bin/kernel.bin

    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiling the OS"
    @cat bin/boot.bin bin/kernel.bin > bin/os.bin

    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiling the Floopy image"
    @dd if=/dev/zero of=bin/floopy.img bs=1024 count=1440
    @dd conv=notrunc if=bin/os.bin of=bin/floopy.img

    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Compiled."

run:
    @echo "${bold}${green}[INFO]${reset} Launching the VM:"
    @qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -drive format=raw,file=bin/floopy.img -m 4G -cpu host -smp 2 -vga virtio -display sdl,gl=on
...
```

#### Solution

Saving the initial value of the `DL` register, which was set up by BIOS, before the control was given to the bootloader, solved the issue.

*fixed bootloader*

```
org 0x7C00

%define color_black   0
%define color_blue    1
%define color_green   2
%define color_cyan    3
%define color_red     4
%define color_magenta 5
%define color_orange  6
%define color_gray    7
%define color_yellow  14
%define color_white   15

;;;;;;;;
; INIT ;
;;;;;;;;

; save DL (drive number) value from the BIOS
mov [drive_number], dl


clear_screen:
    ; Int 0x10
    ; AH = 06h
    ; AL = number of lines by which to scroll up (00h = clear entire window)
    ; BH = attribute used to write blank lines at bottom of window
    ; CH, CL = row, column of window's upper left corner
    ; DH, DL = row, column of window's lower right corner

    mov ax, 0x0600                              ; AH = 6 = Scroll Window Up, AL = 0 = clear window
    mov bh, color_black << 4 | color_magenta    ; Attribute to clear screen with (White on Red)
    xor cx, cx                                  ; Clear window from 0, 0
    mov dx, 25 << 8 | 80                        ; Clear window to 24, 80
    int 0x10                                    ; Clear the screen

    mov ah, 0x02                                ; Set cursor
    mov bh, 0x00                                ; Page 0
    mov dx, 0x00                                ; Row = 0, col = 0
    int 0x10



set_custom_cursor:
    ; Int 0x10
    ; AH = 01h
    ; CH = start scan line of character matrix (0-1fH; 20H=no cursor)
    ; CL = end scan line of character matrix (0-1fH)

    mov ax, 0x0100                              ; AH = 1 = Set Cursor Shape & Size, AL = 0 = nothing
    mov ch, 0x1                                 ; Sets the width of the cursor, the higher the thicker
    mov cl, 0x10                                ; Sets the height of the cursor, the less the higher
    int 0x10

; bootloader start-up message
print_start_up_message:
    mov si, start_up_message 
    call print_string_buffer

    ; move cursor
    mov ah, 0x02
    inc dh
    mov dl, 0
    int 0x10

; set up DX for disk loading
mov dh, 0x1       ; number of sectors that will be loaded into memory
mov dl, [drive_number]       ; drive number to load (0 = boot disk)

; set up ES:BX memory address to load sectors into
mov bx, 0x1000  ; load sector to memory address 0x1000
mov es, bx      ; ES = 0x1000 
mov bx, 0x0       ; ES:BX = 0x1000:0 (segment:offset)

; set up segment registers for RAM
mov ax, 0x1000
mov ds, ax      ; data segment
mov es, ax      ; extra segment
mov fs, ax       
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax      ; stack segment


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; BOOTLOADER ENTRY POINT ; 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
call disk_load  ; loads kernel into memory
jmp 0x1000:0x0


;;;;;;;;;;;
; IMPORTS ;
;;;;;;;;;;;

%include "src/utils/print.asm"
%include "src/disk.asm"


;;;;;;;
; VAR ;
;;;;;;;

start_up_message: db "Bootloader bootstrap", 0
drive_number: resb 8


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; MAGIC NUMBERS ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Thank you for supplying your full code.  What is the specific question you have?

Comment: I would like to know what is the issue. QEMU launches, prints the message from the bootloader, and freezes afterwards. Whereas I expected the kernel to launch, thus printing the OS message.

Comment: You should not force the drive value of `0`, just use what the bios passed to you. `0` will typically be the floppy and `-drive` creates a hard disk by default.

Comment: @Jester.
Could you be so kind to elaborate on your idea? Are you talking about setting the drive to value `0` for the BIOS interrupt or is it about a `qemu` argument?

Comment: Before the BIOS transfers control to your bootloader (at physical address 0x07c00) it sets the `DL` register to the boot drive. You should use the value in register `DL` (you can save it in memory if you need to) and use that value for disk reads using Int 13h. If you hard code to zero then that is always going to be floppy drive 0. The way you launch QEMU the hard coded value would be wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael Petch. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov dl, 0x0       ; drive number to load (0 = boot disk)
> ```

You already solved the main issue with the help of @Jester and @MichaelPetch.
A number of problems still remain:

- problem 1

  > ```
  > org 0x7C00
  > %define color_black   0
  > ...
  > mov [drive_number], dl
  > ```

  Probably you're accustomed to your emulator (qemu) launching your bootloader with zeroed segment registers. On many systems this will not be the case! If you care about developing robust software then at least add next to your bootloader:

  ```
  org  0x7C00
  %define color_black   0
  ...
  xor  ax, ax
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  es, ax
  mov  ss, ax             ; Keep these two together
  mov  sp, 0x7C00         ;  and in this order
  cld                     ; So LODSB functions allright
  mov  [drive_number], dl ; Depends on DS=0
  ...
  ```
- problem 2

  > ```
  > mov ax, 0x1000
  > mov ds, ax      ; data segment
  > mov es, ax      ; extra segment
  > mov fs, ax       
  > mov gs, ax
  > mov ss, ax      ; stack segment
  > call disk_load  ; loads kernel into memory
  > jmp 0x1000:0x0
  > ```

  Because you setup these segment registers even before loading the kernel via the *disk_load* procedure, there's no way that the *disk_load* procedure can display its messages, be it *disk_error* or *disk_success*.
  What is even worse is that you change the SS segment register and don't follow with assigning a suitable SP register. For now, this poses no problem because you only load a single sector. But imagine what will happen once your project grows and you load eg. 100 sectors. Then whatever value happens to be in SP would (combined with the new SS) create havoc in the kernel and it would be hard to detect that error...
  In conclusion, change these segment registers and SP in the first lines of the kernel (that for readability also could do with an `org 0` on top , even if that setting should happen to be the default).
- problem 3

  The *print_string_buffer* procedure relies on DL and DH holding a suitable column and row indication, but when invoked from within *disk_load* (to show an error or success message) this will not be the case! There's no telling if or where these messages would appear.
- problem 4

  > ```
  > mov dx, 25 << 8 | 80           ; Clear window to 24, 80
  > ```

  The lower right corner of the 80x25 screen is at (79,24). This instruction should read: `mov dx, 24 << 8 | 79`.
- problem 5

  > ```
  > start_up_message: db "Bootloader bootstrap", 0
  > drive_number: resb 8
  > ```

  The storage for the *drive_number* requires just 1 byte. Don't use `resb 8` that reserves 8 bytes, but simply write:

  ```
  start_up_message: db "Bootloader bootstrap", 0
  drive_number:     db 0
  ```